# How to save user search input when going to a new page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
let navigate = useNavigate(); 
const routeChange = () =>{ 
  let path = `/ProductsNew`; 
  navigate(path);
}

const wrapperFunction = () => {
  routeChange();
  props.onSubmit(innerSearch)
}
```

I have an API full of data that I fill in my ag-grid-react table. But when I press search and go to the new page, the search gets wiped which I know why, I just can't seem to save the search value.

Comment: use query params

Comment: There are many places to store such as redux store, query parameters, web storage, and persistent to the database. You should pick one based on your requirements.

Comment: Do you just want to save the user input or the API response as well?

Comment: I'd like to save both. So if I search "apple" and hit enter, the page would change and the table would show only rows/values with "apple" in it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are plenty of options to store data, everything from creating Component wrappers using [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), using storage in form of a cookie to using the local storage API or more perhaps commonly used for searches using post and gets variables.

Since post data is for server-side it won't be available for you using react. But as far as get goes in js you can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) or if you happen to use ReactRouter as it seems you can use [useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.5/hooks/use-search-params#usesearchparams).

You can find examples for all of the provided functions at the address I've linked them to. Good luck,